# ¿Cómo integrar datos de base de datos en una matriz asociativa de PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo el router que define mi menú.

```
$router->define(
    [
        'inicio'         => 'controllers/inicio.php',
        'sobre-nosotros' => 'controllers/sobre-nosotros.php',
        'blog'           => 'controllers/blog.php',
        'contactos'      => 'controllers/contactos.php',
    ]
);
```

Quiero coger datos de router de base de datos en vez de tener que escribirlo, pero no logro incorporar el associative array dentro de mi router. He intentado un `foreach`:

```
$menu = $pdo->query("
    SELECT title FROM menu
    ORDER BY priority DESC
;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$router->define(
    [
        foreach ($menu as $item) {
            $item->title => 'Controllers/'.$item->title.'.php',
        }
    ]
);
```

Me tira el siguiente error:

> unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedo probarlo por no tener más código pero prueba con esto:

```
$menu = $pdo->query("
    SELECT title FROM menu
    ORDER BY priority DESC
;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$misroutes = array();

foreach ($menu as $item) {
    $misroutes += array(
        $item->title => 'Controllers/'.$item->title.'.php',
    );
}

$router->define($misroutes);
```

El objetivo es definirme el array antes del define y luego pasárselo como parámetro, espero que te valga, si te da otro error, postéalo y veo si puedo ajustarlo.

P.D: el error que te salía era un "Oye, no me puedes poner un forearch dentro de la definición de un array!"

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciona... Añado el resultado de tú método en mi pregunta

Comment: añade por favor el signo más en vez de corchetes `[]` para que quede asi: `$misroutes += array(`  y marcare tu respuesta como correcta! :)

Comment: Ajustado! Gracias por el detalle jaja

Answer (score 1):

No puedes definir un array de esa manera, poniendo un foreach en la declaracion, tienes que construir el array por fuera, puedes probar así:

```
<?php

$menu = $pdo->query("
    SELECT title FROM menu
    ORDER BY priority DESC
;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// inicializas el array()
$arrayRuta = array();

foreach ($menu as $item) {
   // agregas los elementos al array: array[clave] = 'valor'
   $arrayRuta[ $item->title ] = 'Controllers/'.$item->title.'.php';
}

// pasas el array como argumento
$router->define($arrayRuta);
```